# jquery form on success display message generate from server

Tags: jquery

I have

```
<div id="infoMessage" class="infoMessage"><?php echo $message;?></div>
```

which the $message will generate from the server when POST.

How to I do if I wanted to display the infoMessage once the ajax success

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "the/form",
   data: $(\'.target\').serialize(),
   success: function() {
    alert("done");
    // how to show the infoMessage ?
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "the/form",
   data: $(\'.target\').serialize(),
   success: function(data) {
    //alert("done");
    $('#infoMessage').html(data);
    }
  });
```

You have to echo the message in you ajax file(the/form)

Comment: Unsure why but when echo 'data' return nothing, but I still accepting this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "the/form",
   data: $(\'.target\').serialize(),
   success: function(data) { // data is a callback variable which stores info echoed in PHP file during transfer, so you have to $message there to get it here
    alert(data); // this will alert it
    }
  });
```

HERE INSTEAD OF FUNCTION(DATA) YOU CAN USE ANY VARIABLE TO STORE AJAX RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code instead of what you have.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "the/form",
   data: $(\'.target\').serialize(),
   success: function(data) {
    alert(data); //data contains the ajax response
    $("#infoMessage").html(data); //you set here where to ajax response will be displayed
    }
  });
```